# How To Have Different ReplyTo Addresses for Different Email Addresses Using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Just curious if its possible using phpmailer to send an email to 2 different recipients and each recipient would have a different reply to address.  Right now I am sending a bcc to myself but in order to reply I have to hit reply all and the delete my address so I dont send it to my self.  For example

phpmailer sends 1 email to...
recipient1@domain.com -->  when they get the email hit reply it replies to recipient2@domain.com
recipient2@domain.com -->  when they get the email hit reply it replies to recipient1@domain.com

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So simply set new `replyTo` value

Answer (score 0):

Set a different reply-to address in each message. It is necessary to send two separate messages to do this – you can't send one message that acts differently for each recipient.

In message 1:

```
$mail->addReplyTo('recipient2@domain.com');
```

In message 2:

```
$mail->addReplyTo('recipient1@domain.com');
```

However, do note that this method is called *add*ReplyTo and not *set*ReplyTo, because it's quite legitimate to have multiple reply-to addresses, and if you use the same PHPMailer instance to send your two messages, you need to call `$mail->clearReplyTos()` to reset the reply-to list between each send.